# How to Parse string Values to xml and bind it to dataset

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

i am trying to retrive 5 column from database, in one is type of XML . while returning to dataset it is treated as string. i need to extract that values as xml and bind to another dataset.

for eg : if my query returns 5 column to dataset, one column is xml. i need to extract that values and store it to another dataset as xml .

i tried to use `dstDataset.Tables[0][3].toString();`  it returned the entire xml as string. now i need to parse as xml  and bind to another dataset.

i hope you pepole got my question.

Comment: So, just to make sure we understand correctly: You want to extract some XML, and insert the whole XML-set into another dataset "as-is"? (I.e., no need to extract individual pieces of data from the XML?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the following code:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("table1");
dataTable.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);

string xmlData = "<XmlDS><table1><col1>Value1</col1></table1><table1><col1>Value2</col1></table1></XmlDS>";

System.IO.StringReader xmlSR = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlData);

dataSet.ReadXml(xmlSR, XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema);
```

If you replace xmlData with your the data from the column and make sure the schema is correct this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
(...)
XDocument xmlXDoc = XDocument.Parse(dstDataset.Tables[0][3].toString());
```

Then you can get the XML with:

```
xmlXDoc.ToString()
```

Or, if you prefer it without formatting (indented XML):

```
xmlXDoc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)
```

More info about LINQ to XML: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387044.aspx

Comment: XDocument xmlXDoc = XDocument.Parse(dstSection.Tables[0][3].toString()); this line gives me error . saying that you cannot  apply indexing  with [] an expression  of type 'System.Data.DataDatable

Comment: Strange... given that this gives you a string, as you wrote in your question: `dstDataset.Tables[0][3].toString();`, then `XDocument.Parse()` should be able to parse that string if it contains valid XML. You might try to define it as a variable first: 
`String myXml = dstDataset.Tables[0][3].toString();`, then pass that as a parameter instead, to make sure you're really gettign what you expect from the DataTable.